# SQL/ORA-00933 SQL Command Not Properly Ended

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

I'm executing the following query:

```
select count(*),ACTION_DATE from SUMMARY group by ACTION_DATE where NUM_ACTIONS=500;
```

which is giving me ORA-00933 SQL Command not properly ended and I'm not sure why.

SUMMARY is the table, ACTION_DATE and NUM_ACTIONS are columns. So what I'm expecting is each date with num_actions=500.

If anybody can see what's wrong with the command it'd be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: `where` comes before `group by`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2065706

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause must be before the `GROUP BY`.

[See oracle documentation about SELECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2065646)

```
SELECT COUNT(*), action_date
FROM summary 
WHERE num_actions = 500
GROUP BY action_date
```

Comment: @teoreda No, it's not copied/pasted. I first answered with the syntax of OP. Then I edited my answer to modify the format I use everyday and add link and explanation. Then I saw your answer...

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by:

> Cause: The SQL statement ends with an inappropriate clause. For
>   example, an ORDER BY clause may have been included in a CREATE VIEW or
>   INSERT statement. ORDER BY cannot be used to create an ordered view or
>   to insert in a certain order.

You have **WHERE** after **GROUP BY**

Change the query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), ACTION_DATE 
FROM SUMMARY 
WHERE NUM_ACTIONS = 500 
GROUP BY ACTION_DATE;
```